# How do I use align captions at the bottom while aligning the pictures at the top?

Tags: tables, captions, minipage

I am trying to get the pictures to align at the top while the captions are on the same line at the bottom using `minipage` and `tabular`. *I also need to write source caption beneath each image which I am trying to place directly under them (this is already done in my attempt).*

[image: desire]

My attempt: that produces the result below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}        
\usepackage{float}

\newcommand{\imagesource}[1]{{\scriptsize Source: #1}}      

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
    \makebox[\textwidth]{\makebox[1\textwidth]{%
    % \begin{minipage}[t][][b]{0.2\textwidth}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth} % [t][][b]
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ @{} r @{} }
        \includegraphics[width = .9\linewidth]{image1.png} \\
        \imagesource{(EU 2020)}
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{This is a caption for the first image.}\label{fig:image1}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ @{} r @{} }
        \includegraphics[width = .5\linewidth]{image2.png} \\
        \imagesource{(IEA 2019)}
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{This is a caption for the second image.}\label{fig:image2}
    \end{minipage}\hfill}
    }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the  `\imagesource` command?

Comment: @Bernard, it adds the source caption (EU 2020) and (IEA 2019) respectively.

Comment: @Bernard I forgot to add the custom command in the example code, sorry. I have edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should result in the expected output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}        
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\newcommand{\imagesource}[1]{{\scriptsize Source: #1}}      

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.475\textwidth} % [t][][b]
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}[t]{ @{} r @{} }
        \includegraphics[width = .9\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image} \\
        \imagesource{(EU 2020)}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.475\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}[t]{ @{} r @{} }
        \includegraphics[width = .5\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image} \\
        \imagesource{(IEA 2019)}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
    
     \begin{minipage}[t]{.475\textwidth}
       \caption{This is a caption for the first image.}\label{fig:image1}
     \end{minipage}\hfill
     \begin{minipage}[t]{.475\textwidth}
        \caption{This is a caption for the second image.}\label{fig:image2}
     \end{minipage}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! How can I align the top left corner of the image with the captions under the images? Also is it possible to align both images to left corner?

Comment: Like that? https://i.stack.imgur.com/AP1DN.png Just remove both `\centering` commands to get this output.

Comment: Exactly, thank you! You get a nicer text though. My caption is getting outside the left figure though. https://i.imgur.com/0ZAPYjP.png

Comment: @Clone: How exactly did you produce teh output you showed in your last comment? Probably this has something to do with teh `caption` package centering captions that only span one line? You can turn off this behaviour by using `\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false}` in the preamble (to affect all captions in the whole document) or inside of the corresponding `figure` environment (to only affect the caption(s)  of this particular `figure`.

Comment: Thank you, `\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false` aligned it to the left corner. Here is my full preamble: https://pastebin.com/Zfsd1KQD

Answer (score 2):

I would do that withe `floatrow` and `copyrightbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}
\newcommand{\imagesource}[1]{{\scriptsize Source: #1}}% doesn’t work with floatrow

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\floatsetup{heightadjust=object, valign=t}\captionsetup{textfont=it}
    \begin{floatrow}
        \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Laurel \& Hardy, Busy Bodies.}\label{fig:image1}}{%
        \copyrightbox[b]{\includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{Busy_Bodies}}{\raggedleft(EU 2020)}
        }

        \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{The Hunting of the Snark.}\label{fig:image2}}{%
        \copyrightbox[b]{\includegraphics[width = 0.8\linewidth]{snark}}{\raggedleft(IEA 2019)}
        }
    \end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting solution, thank you!