# How do I force caption to align under the image?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions, minipage

How can I force caption to align to the left corner of the image above it and also not be wider than the image in this code example?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}        % for source
\usepackage{float}          
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % valign
\newcommand{\imagesource}[1]{{\scriptsize Source: #1}}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.475\textwidth} % [t][][b]
        \begin{tabular}[t]{ @{} r @{} }
        \includegraphics[width = .9\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image} \\
        \imagesource{(EU 2020)}
       \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.475\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}[t]{ @{} r @{} }
        \includegraphics[width = .7\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image} \\
        \imagesource{(IEA 2019)}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
     \begin{minipage}[t]{.475\textwidth}
       \caption{This is a caption for the first image.}\label{fig:image1}
     \end{minipage}\hfill
     \begin{minipage}[t]{.475\textwidth}
        \caption{This is a caption for the second image.}\label{fig:image2}
     \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: xxx]

Comment: If I compile your document, I get a different output than you. In my output, the captions each take up two lines, resulting in a different alignment. See also [my recent comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567453/how-do-i-use-align-captions-at-the-bottom-while-aligning-the-pictures-at-the-top/567462?noredirect=1#comment1430711_567462) under the answer to your last question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

With use of `tabular` instead of the `minipage`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}           % for source
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % valign
\newcommand{\imagesource}[1]{{\smallskip\hfill\scriptsize Source: #1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.45\linewidth} p{0.34\linewidth}}
\includegraphics[valign=t]{example-image}

\imagesource{(EU 2020)}
    & 
\includegraphics[valign=t]{example-image}

\imagesource{(IEA 2019)}    \\
\caption{This is a caption for the first image.}
\label{fig:image1}
    &   \caption{This is a caption for the second image.}
        \label{fig:image2}
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
You may liked alternative solution with use of the `copyrightbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}        % for source
\newcommand{\imagesource}[1]{\hfill\scriptsize Source: #1}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\CRB@setcopyrightparagraphstyle}{\raggedleft} % new
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.45\linewidth}p{0.34\linewidth}}
\copyrightbox[b]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}{(EU 2020)}
    & 
\copyrightbox[b]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}{(IEA 2019)}    
    \\[-3ex]
\caption{This is a caption for the first image.}
\label{fig:image1}
    &   \caption{This is a caption for the second image.}
        \label{fig:image2}
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks interesting, but I need to have the sources aligned to the bottom right corner of each image. Otherwise it is just what I am looking for.

Comment: @Clone, see edited answer.

Comment: very nice solution but how do I make these figuers to align with the text outside of the figure? https://i.imgur.com/kcwQiNB.png

Comment: @Clone, I do not understand you. How to be aligned? In the first  example is provided solution for which you ask in question, the second example only show, how I would present this images. You not need to use the second example, if you not liked it.

Answer (score 3):

The following MWE allows to reproduce the output shown in the original question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}        % for source
\usepackage{float}          
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % valign
\newcommand{\imagesource}[1]{{\scriptsize Source: #1}}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{fullpage} % full wide page, small margins
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.475\textwidth} % [t][][b]
        \begin{tabular}[t]{ @{} r @{} }
        \includegraphics[width = .9\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image} \\
        \imagesource{(EU 2020)}
       \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.475\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}[t]{ @{} r @{} }
        \includegraphics[width = .7\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image} \\
        \imagesource{(IEA 2019)}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
     \begin{minipage}[t]{.475\textwidth}
       \caption{This is a caption for the first image.}\label{fig:image1}
     \end{minipage}\hfill
     \begin{minipage}[t]{.475\textwidth}
        \caption{This is a caption for the second image.}\label{fig:image2}
     \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

As already speculated [in the comments to the previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567453/how-do-i-use-align-captions-at-the-bottom-while-aligning-the-pictures-at-the-top/567462?noredirect=1#comment1430711_567462), this behaviour is due to the `caption` package that automatically horizontally centers captions that only span one line. You can turn off this behaviour globally (in the preamble)  or locally (in the corresponding `figure` environment) by using `\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false}`. This will result in the expected output:

[image]

Comment: You can change the width of the caption using \captionsetup (inside the minipage).